# Errors I face at the final step of creating an installer for my Qt app

Tags: c++, qt, installation

**EDITED**:
Hi all,

I used the Qt Documentations for creating an installer for my Qt app using Qt Installer Framework.
I think I'm at the final step. Please have a look at the issue:

I have a *package_directory* folder on my Windows Desktop with [these](http://uploads.im/plRu1.jpg) sub-folders. The *config.xml* file contains [this](https://paste.ofcode.org/PMEfGvXWZXWipGeenYhd98). The *data* subfolder contains the *data.7z* file. I then created a *licens.txt* file on my Desktop. The *meta* subfolder contains a *package.xml* file with [this](https://paste.ofcode.org/35Ph56Mf3uGWZ6kAZ4NzpD2) content.

Then I created a folder named *Result* on my Desktop and pasted the *Cal.exe* file from the *Release* folder onto it.
And finally Ran the following command:

**C:\Qt\QtIFW2.0.3\bin\binarycreator.exe -c C:\Users\CS\Desktop\package_directory\config\config.xml -p C:\Users\CS\Desktop\package_directory\packages C:\Users\CS\Desktop\Result\Cal.exe**

The installer was created in the *Result* folder. But I got the following message from the command line:

```
Warning: The <Name> tag in the 'C:/Users/CS/Desktop/package_directory/packag
es/com.vendor.product/meta/package.xml' is ignored - the installer uses the path
element right before the 'meta' ('com.vendor.product').
C:\Qt\QtIFW2.0.3\bin>
```

Should I ignore it? If not how to solve it, too, please?

The installer file exists in the *Result* folder on Desktop. When I install it and select a folder on *Start Menu* (say *Accessories* or *Start Up*) to have the shortcut of the program, no shortcut will be created or saved there!! :(

What is the reason for that problem and how should I solve it please?

Comment: Isn't there any solution!?

Comment: What is the problem with asking these questions? Shouldn't I ask a programming issue here!!!??